# how to make details tag open when converting to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

In my html page there is a div element which contains 2-3 details tag(By default all the details tag will be in collapsed mode) with tables inside it..I am trying to convert this html div contents to canvas.with that canvas i m creating a pdf.

below is the code

```
enter code here
            <div id="result">
                    <details style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <summary>
                            <b>Name</b>
                        </summary>
                        <table id="table1" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="35%">Subject</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Issues</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Issues</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </details>
                    <details style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <summary>
                            <b>Name</b>
                        </summary>
                        <table id="table2" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="35%">Subject</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Issues</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>From</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </details>
                    <details style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <summary>
                            <b>Name</b>
                        </summary>
                        <table id="table3" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="35%">Subject</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Issues</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>From</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </details>

            </div>
```

Canvas convertion and pdf creation code

```
enter code here
            $("body").on("click", "#btnExport", function () {
                    html2canvas($('#Result')[0], {
                        onrendered: function (canvas) {
                            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                            var docDefinition = {
                                content: [{
                                    image: data,
                                    width: 500
                                }]
                            };
                            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Table.pdf");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

But the problem i am able to create a pdf with details tag closed.i want to have the entire content in pdf.

Is there any way to change expand this details when converting to canvas?

Answer (score 1):

## [`<details open>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#Attributes)

`<details>` has an `[open]` attribute. 
**Demo 1 (JavaScript):**
- Collects all `<details>` into a NodeList then converts it into an array.
- Iterates through the new array with a `for...of` loop.
- On each iteration it switches each `<details>` `[open]` attribute with `.toggleAttribute()` method.

---

**Demo 2 (jQuery):**
- On `.each()` `<details>`
- Make its `[open]` attribute `true` using `.attr()` method.

---

Run either version before calling `html2canvas()` of course.

---

### Demo 1

```js
const detailsArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('details'));

for (let details of detailsArray) {
  details.toggleAttribute('open');
}
```

```css
details {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px ridge #bbb;
}

summary {
  border: 3px inset #333;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Read More...</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</details>


<details>
  <summary>Read More...</summary>
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</details>


<details>
  <summary>Read More...</summary>
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</details>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
$('details').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('open', true);
});
```

```css
details {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px ridge #bbb;
}

summary {
  border: 3px inset #333;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Read More...</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</details>


<details>
  <summary>Read More...</summary>
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</details>


<details>
  <summary>Read More...</summary>
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</details>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried above code.it is making the details tag opened in html page also.i just want the details tag to be opened in the canvas.

Comment: Try hard coding `<details open>`. If that doesn't work the plugin might not be compatible, which is possible since `<details>` is relatively new. Did you place the new code outside your function or inside, if the latter -- did you place before the `html2canvas(...`?